# What is the proper and cleaner way to hide parameters with sensitive data in URL with .Net (backend) + Angular app?

Tags: c#, .net, angular, http, webapi

For example I have an endpoint which shows me details about certain user where **2 is a user ID.**

```
http://localhost:4200/user/2
```

My question is how to hide this last parameter from URL address with proper way.

My goal is to have only something like

```
http://localhost:4200/user
```

I am using .Net for Backend and Angular for client app.

Controller.cs

```
[HttpGet("{userId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<AppUserDTO>> GetUserById(int userId)
{
    var user = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);
    var mappedUser = _mapper.Map<AppUserDTO>(user);
    return Ok(mappedUser);
}
```

****I solved my problem but not sure if this is right**** from a programming point of view. I feel like there could be a better and cleaner solution. Code below.

users.service.ts

```
  private userId;

  set userToSet(userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
  }

  get userToGet() {
    return this.userId;
  }

  getUserById(userId) {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + 'api/users/' + userId);
  }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'user', component: UserDetailComponent },
```

user-list.component.ts (I am using this function when click selected record on the table, then go to the user details page. The userID is setting here)

```
  loadUserDetails(userId) {
    this.usersService.userToSet = userId;
    this.router.navigate(['/user']);
  }
```

user-detail.component.ts (This is the detail page component where the userID is retrieved and the correct data is displayed)

```
  user: AppUser;
  userId: number;

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadUserById();
  }

  loadUserById() {
    this.userId = this.usersService.userToGet;
    this.usersService.getUserById(this.userId).subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**The biggest security issue for sensitive data in your example is using http**. With http data travels unencrypted through the network and anyone can read them. Putting sentitive data on the request body instead of in the url does not really make a difference in this case.

In any case, you certainly don't want to pass sensitive data on route data or query string parameters because the url is not encrypted. Check [model binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0), I think you probably want to use `FromBody` or `FromForm`.

Comment: I am using http because this is for develop/teach purpose only. Generally I want to prevent other user from move to another user details page by edit userID in the URL address. Thank you for your thoughts.